# The relationship was not loaded because the type is not available error while hosting website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, github

I am using Asp.net MVC, Entity Framework with data first approach. My website is working fine on localhost. I have used github and hosted website on appharbor. My hosted website throws an error

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
>   The relationship 'Model.FK_AdImage_ToTable' was not loaded because the type 'Model.Ad' is not available.
>   The following information may be useful in resolving the previous error:
>   The required property 'AdViews' does not exist on the type 'Inspinia_MVC5_SeedProject.Models.Ad'.

**Note:** Previously I was using table `AdViews` but now I'm no longer using it and I have deleted this table. (`AdViews` was child table of `Ad`)

I have clone the repository to : `C:\Users\Irfan\Documents\GitHub\repoName`

Now `C:\Users\Irfan\Documents\GitHub\repoName\MVC5_Seed_Project\Inspinia_MVC5_SeedProject\Models\Ad.cs` code is:

```
namespace Inspinia_MVC5_SeedProject.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Ad
    {
        public Ad()
        {
            this.AdImages = new HashSet<AdImage>();
            this.AdTags = new HashSet<AdTag>();
            this.Bids = new HashSet<Bid>();
            this.Comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
            this.Reporteds = new HashSet<Reported>();
            this.SaveAds = new HashSet<SaveAd>();
            this.JobSkills = new HashSet<JobSkill>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
        public string postedBy { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime time { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> price { get; set; }
        public string isnegotiable { get; set; }
        public string subcategory { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> type { get; set; }
        public string condition { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public int views { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AdImage> AdImages { get; set; }
        public virtual AdsLocation AdsLocation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AdTag> AdTags { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Bid> Bids { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public virtual LaptopAd LaptopAd { get; set; }
        public virtual MobileAd MobileAd { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Reported> Reporteds { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SaveAd> SaveAds { get; set; }
        public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
        public virtual CompanyAd CompanyAd { get; set; }
        public virtual JobAd JobAd { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<JobSkill> JobSkills { get; set; }
        public virtual CarAd CarAd { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`C:\Users\Irfan\Documents\GitHub\repoName\Models\Model1.edmx.diagram` code is: (**Note:** This code contains reference of `AdView`. I have bold those 3 lines)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
 <!-- EF Designer content (DO NOT EDIT MANUALLY BELOW HERE) -->
  <edmx:Designer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
    <!-- Diagram content (shape and connector positions) -->
    <edmx:Diagrams>
      <Diagram DiagramId="815ee3eabea747c5bd662a6f75d487f4" Name="Diagram1" ZoomLevel="94">
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.C__MigrationHistory" Width="1.5" PointX="0.75" PointY="0.75" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.Ad" Width="1.5" PointX="68.25" PointY="46.625" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.AdImage" Width="1.5" PointX="71.375" PointY="45.875" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.AdsLocation" Width="1.5" PointX="55.5" PointY="59.75" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.AdTag" Width="1.5" PointX="63" PointY="49.625" />
        **<EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.AdView" Width="1.5" PointX="61.5" PointY="44.875" />**     
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.Answer" Width="1.5" PointX="8" PointY="120.375" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.AnswerReply" Width="1.5" PointX="5.75" PointY="124.75" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.AnswerReplyVote" Width="1.5" PointX="8.75" PointY="125" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.AnswerVote" Width="1.5" PointX="11" PointY="120.75" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.AspNetRole" Width="1.5" PointX="0.75" PointY="49.5" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.AspNetUserClaim" Width="1.5" PointX="5.25" PointY="60.125" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.AspNetUserLogin" Width="1.5" PointX="5.25" PointY="40" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.AspNetUser" Width="1.5" PointX="6" PointY="44.375" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.Bid" Width="1.5" PointX="62.5" PointY="51.75" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.CarAd" Width="1.5" PointX="72.75" PointY="60.125" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.CarBrand" Width="1.5" PointX="77.75" PointY="60.125" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.CarModel" Width="1.5" PointX="75.5" PointY="60" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.Chat" Width="1.5" PointX="4.5" PointY="35.875" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.Comment" Width="1.5" PointX="62" PointY="57.125" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.CommentReply" Width="1.5" PointX="62.375" PointY="61.25" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.CommentReplyVote" Width="1.5" PointX="58.875" PointY="61.375" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.CommentVote" Width="1.5" PointX="58.75" PointY="57.375" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.FollowQuestion" Width="1.5" PointX="2.875" PointY="112.375" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.FollowTag" Width="1.5" PointX="29.875" PointY="71.125" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.Friend" Width="1.5" PointX="0.875" PointY="53" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.LaptopAd" Width="1.5" PointX="73.375" PointY="50.75" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.LaptopBrand" Width="1.5" PointX="79.25" PointY="50.875" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.LaptopModel" Width="1.5" PointX="76.25" PointY="50.625" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.Mobile" Width="1.5" PointX="81.125" PointY="47.625" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.MobileAd" Width="1.5" PointX="75.375" PointY="47.5" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.MobileModel" Width="1.5" PointX="78.375" PointY="46.625" IsExpanded="true" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.popularPlace" Width="1.5" PointX="23.375" PointY="58.5" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.Question" Width="1.5" PointX="7.75" PointY="114.75" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.QuestionReply" Width="1.5" PointX="13.625" PointY="116.25" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.QuestionReplyVote" Width="1.5" PointX="8.25" PointY="111" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.QuestionTag" Width="1.5" PointX="11.375" PointY="109" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.QuestionView" Width="1.5" PointX="1.125" PointY="114.875" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.QuestionVote" Width="1.5" PointX="11.625" PointY="113.375" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.Reported" Width="1.5" PointX="64.25" PointY="46" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.ReportedQuestion" Width="1.5" PointX="2.25" PointY="119.875" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.ReportedTag" Width="1.5" PointX="39.625" PointY="69.375" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.Tag" Width="1.5" PointX="34.25" PointY="73.375" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Ad_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AdImage_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AdsLocation_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AdTag_ToTable" />
        **<AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AdView_ToTable" />**
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Bid_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CarAd_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Comment_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_LaptopAds_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_MobileAds_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Reported_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AdsLocation_ToTable_2" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AdTag_ToTable_1" />
        **<AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AdView_ToTable_1" />**
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Answer_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Answer_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AnswerReply_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AnswerVote_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AnswerReply_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AnswerReplyVote_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AnswerReplyVote_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AnswerVote_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_dbo_AspNetUserClaims_dbo_AspNetUsers_UserId" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_dbo_AspNetUserLogins_dbo_AspNetUsers_UserId" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Bid_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Chat_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Chat_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Comment_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CommentReply_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CommentReplyVote_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CommentVote_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_FollowQuestion_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_FollowTag_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Friend_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Friend_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_LaptopBrand_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_LaptopModel_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Mobile_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_MobileModel_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_popularPlace_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_popularPlace_ToTable_2" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Question_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_QuestionReply_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_QuestionReplyVote_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_QuestionView_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_QuestionVote_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Reported_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_ReportedQuestion_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_ReportedTag_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Tag_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Tag_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CarAd_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CarModels_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CommentReply_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CommentVote_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CommentReplyVote_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_FollowQuestion_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_FollowTag_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_LaptopAds_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_LaptopModel_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_MobileModel_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_MobileAds_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_QuestionReply_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_QuestionTag_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_QuestionView_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_QuestionVote_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_ReportedQuestion_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_QuestionReplyVote_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_QuestionTag_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_ReportedTag_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.AspNetUserRoles" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.City" Width="1.5" PointX="26.875" PointY="58.375" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AdsLocation_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_City_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_City_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_popularPlace_ToTable" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.SaveAd" Width="1.5" PointX="61.5" PointY="47" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_SaveAd_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_SaveAd_ToTable_1" />
      </Diagram>
    </edmx:Diagrams>
  </edmx:Designer>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

And the code of `C:\Users\Irfan\Documents\GitHub\repoName\MVC5_Seed_Project\Inspinia_MVC5_SeedProject\Models\Model1.edmx.diagram` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
 <!-- EF Designer content (DO NOT EDIT MANUALLY BELOW HERE) -->
  <edmx:Designer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
    <!-- Diagram content (shape and connector positions) -->
    <edmx:Diagrams>
      <Diagram DiagramId="815ee3eabea747c5bd662a6f75d487f4" Name="Diagram1" ZoomLevel="77">
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.C__MigrationHistory" Width="1.5" PointX="0.75" PointY="0.75" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.Ad" Width="1.5" PointX="68.25" PointY="46.625" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.AdImage" Width="1.5" PointX="71.375" PointY="45.875" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.AdsLocation" Width="1.5" PointX="55.5" PointY="59.75" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.AdTag" Width="1.5" PointX="63" PointY="49.625" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.Answer" Width="1.5" PointX="8" PointY="120.375" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.AnswerReply" Width="1.5" PointX="5.75" PointY="124.75" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.AnswerReplyVote" Width="1.5" PointX="8.75" PointY="125" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.AnswerVote" Width="1.5" PointX="11" PointY="120.75" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.AspNetRole" Width="1.5" PointX="0.75" PointY="49.5" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.AspNetUserClaim" Width="1.5" PointX="3" PointY="59.875" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.AspNetUserLogin" Width="1.5" PointX="5.25" PointY="40" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.Bid" Width="1.5" PointX="62.5" PointY="51.75" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.Chat" Width="1.5" PointX="4.5" PointY="35.875" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.Comment" Width="1.5" PointX="62" PointY="57.125" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.CommentReply" Width="1.5" PointX="62.375" PointY="61.25" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.CommentReplyVote" Width="1.5" PointX="58.875" PointY="61.375" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.CommentVote" Width="1.5" PointX="58.75" PointY="57.375" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.FollowQuestion" Width="1.5" PointX="2.875" PointY="112.375" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.FollowTag" Width="1.5" PointX="29.875" PointY="71.125" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.Friend" PointX="8.25" PointY="50.625" Width="1.5" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.LaptopAd" Width="1.5" PointX="73.375" PointY="50.75" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.LaptopBrand" Width="1.5" PointX="79.25" PointY="50.875" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.LaptopModel" Width="1.5" PointX="76.25" PointY="50.625" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.Mobile" Width="1.5" PointX="81.125" PointY="47.625" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.MobileAd" Width="1.5" PointX="75.375" PointY="47.5" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.MobileModel" Width="1.5" PointX="78.375" PointY="46.625" IsExpanded="true" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.popularPlace" Width="1.5" PointX="23.375" PointY="58.5" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.Question" Width="1.5" PointX="7.75" PointY="114.75" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.QuestionReply" Width="1.5" PointX="13.625" PointY="116.25" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.QuestionReplyVote" Width="1.5" PointX="8.25" PointY="111" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.QuestionTag" Width="1.5" PointX="11.375" PointY="109" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.QuestionVote" Width="1.5" PointX="11.625" PointY="113.375" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.Reported" Width="1.5" PointX="64.25" PointY="46" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.ReportedQuestion" Width="1.5" PointX="2.25" PointY="119.875" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.ReportedTag" Width="1.5" PointX="39.625" PointY="69.375" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.Tag" Width="1.5" PointX="34.25" PointY="73.375" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AdImage_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AdsLocation_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AdTag_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Bid_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Comment_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_LaptopAds_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_MobileAds_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Reported_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AdsLocation_ToTable_2" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AdTag_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Answer_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AnswerReply_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AnswerVote_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AnswerReplyVote_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CommentReply_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CommentVote_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CommentReplyVote_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_FollowQuestion_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_FollowTag_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_LaptopAds_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_LaptopModel_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_MobileModel_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_MobileAds_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_QuestionReply_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_QuestionTag_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_QuestionVote_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_ReportedQuestion_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_QuestionReplyVote_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_QuestionTag_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_ReportedTag_ToTable" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.City" Width="1.5" PointX="26.875" PointY="58.375" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AdsLocation_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_popularPlace_ToTable" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.SaveAd" Width="1.5" PointX="61.5" PointY="47" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_SaveAd_ToTable" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.CompanyAnswerReply" Width="1.5" PointX="51" PointY="95.375" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.CompanyImage" Width="1.5" PointX="41" PointY="96.5" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.CompanyOffice" Width="1.5" PointX="40.25" PointY="80.875" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.CompanyQuestion" Width="1.5" PointX="47.25" PointY="93.375" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.FollowCompany" Width="1.5" PointX="44.625" PointY="82.875" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.Review" Width="1.5" PointX="47.25" PointY="83.625" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.ReviewReply" Width="1.5" PointX="49.125" PointY="82.75" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.ReviewVote" Width="1.5" PointX="50" PointY="85.625" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CompanyOffice_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CompanyOffice_ToTable_2" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CompanyReviewReply_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_ReviewVote_ToTable" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.CompanyAnswer" Width="1.5" PointX="49.25" PointY="95.5" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CompanyAnswer_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CompanyAnswerReply_ToTable" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.AspNetUser" Width="1.5" PointX="3" PointY="43.25" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Ad_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Answer_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AnswerReply_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AnswerReplyVote_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_AnswerVote_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_dbo_AspNetUserClaims_dbo_AspNetUsers_UserId" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_dbo_AspNetUserLogins_dbo_AspNetUsers_UserId" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Bid_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Chat_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Chat_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_City_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_City_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Comment_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CommentReply_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CommentReplyVote_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CommentVote_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CompanyAnswer_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CompanyAnswerReply_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CompanyQuestion_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CompanyReviewReply_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_FollowCompany_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_FollowQuestion_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_FollowTag_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Friend_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Friend_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_LaptopBrand_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_LaptopModel_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Mobile_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_MobileModel_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_popularPlace_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_popularPlace_ToTable_2" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Question_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_QuestionReply_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_QuestionReplyVote_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_QuestionVote_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Reported_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_ReportedQuestion_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_ReportedTag_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Review_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_SaveAd_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Tag_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Tag_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.AspNetUserRoles" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.CompanyTag" Width="1.5" PointX="45.625" PointY="79.25" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CompanyTag_ToTable_1" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.CompanyAd" Width="1.5" PointX="57.25" PointY="77.625" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CompanyAd_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CompanyAd_ToTable_2" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.Company" Width="1.5" PointX="42.125" PointY="73.125" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Company_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Company_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Company_ToTable_2" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CompanyAd_ToTable_1" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CompanyOffice_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CompanyQuestion_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CompanyTag_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_FollowCompany_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Image_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_Review_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_ReviewVote_ToTable_1" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.JobAd" Width="1.5" PointX="70.5" PointY="48.5" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.JobSkill" Width="1.5" PointX="70.5" PointY="61" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_JobAd_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_JobSkill_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_JobSkill_ToTable_1" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.CarAd" Width="1.5" PointX="70.5" PointY="52.5" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.CarBrand" Width="1.5" PointX="5.25" PointY="49.5" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.CarModel" Width="1.5" PointX="7.5" PointY="46.375" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CarAd_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CarBrand_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CarModel_ToTable" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CarAd_ToTable_2" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="Model.FK_CarModel_ToTable_1" />
        </Diagram>
    </edmx:Diagrams>
  </edmx:Designer>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Comment: If my given information is not making sense then What else I should mention to help you understand and fix this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any actual relevance to GitHub here? Or did you just use it for version control?

Comment: Actually I was first using Visual studio to push code to github but whenever I create new file or folder I get error on deploying website "File not found" but my website worked fine. Then I installed github for windows and I when I pushed code for first time using github for windows I got bundle of errors one of which is mentioned above.

Comment: Do you have a precompiled views? You have to regenerate it as model changed

Comment: Insure that your model is recompiled

Comment: precompiled views? My views are using only that information that is present in updated model. I have searched the error (`AdViews`) in complete project but no results found. I have updated my model. how to recompile model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created new repository on github and published code and it worked!